# Can't for the life of me get internal speakers working (2017 Intel i5 MacBook)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, mac

I've tried running Fedora 38, Nobara 37, Kubuntu 22.10 and now Ubuntu 22.10 on my 2017 Macbook (Intel i5). In all cases, internal speakers simply will not work. Wired and Bluetooth audio work fine. Pulse Audio appears to recognize the Built-In Audio device in Volume Control, but no sound comes out.

What am I missing? TIA

Comment: See https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux and https://github.com/dalikewara/macbook-linux-drivers/tree/master/mbp-2017-13inch/xubuntu-22.04

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi The problem I've been having is that I'm using the 12" Retina Macbook (not Pro, not Air, not iMac), which most content out there ignores. However, I *just* found this and it solved it! https://github.com/leifliddy/macbook12-audio-driver

Answer (score 2):

Found [this](https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux/issues/102) issue thread, which led to [this driver](https://github.com/leifliddy/macbook12-audio-driver), which worked!